# How are the Craft docs created?

Tags: templating, structure, navigation, documentation

The [Craft documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types) on Section Types state that they themselves are created using a Structure. Can someone explain the method they used here?

What I'd really like to see is the Twig code for the left hand navigation. Are there multiple Structures here (to account for the headings) and if not, how are the headings set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `Documentation` structured section with three entry types.

1. `Heading Only`
2. `Page`
3. `Link`

The `Getting Started`, `Core Concepts`, etc. headers are the `Heading Only` entry type. The only field is has is a title.

The majority of the docs are using the `Page` entry type.

The `Link` entry type is used for the entries like `Full Templating Reference` and `Plugin Development` that open into a new window, and those are their own separate structured sections.

Comment: I'm guessing that `Link` entry type has a checkbox to select whether or not you're linking to an external page. Is this how links such as "Installing and Updating", which links within the same structure, look different than external links like "Full Templating Reference"?

Comment: Or are you doing something more fancy to do those "sub-headings"?  `getDescendants(1).first().url`?

Comment: @RobHodges I think this might be the twig code for that side nav too https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/9362241

Comment: @carlcs The Link entry type has a `Title` and a `Link Url` (i.e. 'docs/templating'). See the gist that @MikePepper linked to for the template code to pull it out.

Comment: Hmm, can I just ask, in the snippet @MikePepper sent, does anyone know what `selEntry` is?

Comment: I think `selEntry` is the entry that's being viewed at the time, so the nav would be included with `{% include "nav.html" with { selEntry: entry } %}`

Comment: Ah, I've got the nav in my master layout (It's a simple site). Just using `entry` on this line e.g. `{% set entryParent = entry.getParent() %}` wouldn't work because it's possible to have a page without an entry?

Comment: @BradBell - are _Installing and Updating_ and _Configuration_ of the Link entry type? If so, how do you indicate whether the link is internal or external, like _Full Templating Reference?_ If not, how do those entries not have their own page content?